# The meaning of the idiom 'be subject to'

Tags: idioms

> This paper is subject to correction.

Without context, I take it to mean:

> This paper may be corrected.

But could there be some context under which it could mean:

> This paper will be corrected.

Comment: This is not an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

subject to correction = may be corrected

It does not mean "will be corrected".  It may contain errors  or omissions and thus may be corrected.  It doesn't mean "It does contain errors and so will be corrected".

> Those products are subject to a 10% duty.

There, however, it means that *if you import these products, expect to pay a 10% duty (absent circumstances that would exempt you from having to pay it).*

Comment: So, you wouldn't say _This paper is subject to correction_ in Daniil Manokhin's example, would you?

Comment: What would the intended meaning be?  Am I trying to tell you that your paper has errors?

Comment: The intended meaning in Daniil Manokhin's example? The example has been provided to say that 'subject to correction' can mean 'will be corrected', so I guess that's the intended meaning.

Comment: It's not something I would personally say when my meaning was "this has errors", and although I have made errors, no one has ever said those words to me with that meaning.  Where I normally encounter *subject to correction* is in contexts where new information may become available and what is written may have to be changed to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the meaning.

You could say:

> I found mistakes in your paper. This paper is subject to correction